# Record image details for each image

Tags: media

I wonder if someone could tell me how to add details for each image I have for my content on my Drupal 7.32 website (say title and description). For Example, I have a Content Type called Info, this has an image field which can have an unlimited number of images. When I upload the image I would like to also add details about the image. I remember seeing a Module that will allow that, but Ive been googling and I cant find it now. If this is not possible then I guess I will have to link the Image to another node and add the detail there. If you take a look at my About Us page on my website (http://www.caerleonlodgehillprimary.org/about-us), it has 3 images at the bottom, I would like to be able to show a title under each one, maybe some description too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are customizing your theme and creating your own template files then this will help you.
This module can solve your problem for adding description for particular image.
https://www.drupal.org/project/image_field_caption
Just follow the installation guidelines and install it.
For title, just go to content type->edit link of image and then look for enable title field and enable that.
Yeah , you need to play a bit of with your codes, need to fetch data for title and description.
Thanks